# Angular mdbootstrap , mdb-tabs ngIf condation if true , tab will index at the end

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

Unfortunately stuck with lots of code  here.  its referenced like so

"ng-uikit-pro-standard": "file:ng-uikit-pro-standard-8.3.0.tgz",

I am just trying to get a tab to show in between 1 and 3 if a condition is true.

normally the website looks like

**Tab intro      |    tab order    | tab complete**

**Tab intro      |     Tab pre registration |  tab order    | tab complete**

normally code to handle this you would do

```
<mdb-tabset #tabs
    <mdb-tab header ="Tab Intro">...
    <mdb-tab *ngIf="requirePreregistration == true" header ="Tab pre registration">...
    <mdb-tab header ="tab order">...
    <mdb-tab header ="tab complete">..
```

but only adds it add the end of the condition is true

**Tab intro     |  tab order    | tab complete  | Tab pre registration**

if false, the tab does not show.  There is allot of code on this page.  What can be done?

the typescript if needed

```
ngOnInit() {
    if(order.type == RequestPaymentType.PreRegrister)
        this.requirePreregistration = true;
}
```

I understand tabs can be created dynamically,  i have tried to give them an index,changeDetectorRef might have a play in this?

ref: https://mdbootstrap.com/

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please reformulate it with pertinent code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply put

add tabOrder , nothing on the typescript side, which I was doing giving me errors, and was down the right path

```
<mdb tabOrder="1"
<mdb tabOrder="2"
```